# Imagick Wrong JPEG library version

Tags: php, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

I'm trying to resize some images using PHP and Imagick, however when I do so I get this error:

ImagickException: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62

There's very little on internet about the problem, although there are a few questions on stackoverflow about it. I can't see any solutions posted to any though.

Does anyone have a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution. I had compiled a later version of libjpeg at some point. I deleted /usr/local/lib/libjpeg*, reinstalled libjpeg and libjpeg-devel from yum, ran ldconfig, recompiled php and everything worked fine!